# How to allow TreeSet to have duplicates?

Tags: java, treeset

I need a solution so my TreeSet don't remove duplicates. It is very important, that it is a TreeSet so no Solution with an Array or so. Actual output is: [Value], but I need output:[value, value]

```
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class FruitTree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>();
        
        ts.add("Value");
        ts.add("Value");

        TreeSet<String> tsDescending = (TreeSet<String>)ts.descendingSet();

        System.out.println(ts);
        System.out.println(tsDescending);

    }
}
```

Comment: A set is unsuitable for this requirement.

Comment: Sets don't allow duplicates by definition. You should use another data structure, although if you really want a TreeSet, you can wrap the Strings in another object without overriden equals or hashCode methods

Comment: Why is it important for you to use a TreeSet?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the original homework/assignment to your question so it is clear what your task is.

Comment: Ah I am certain nobody here speaks my language. Also I do not continue such a senseless homework. Thx anyway.

Comment: @Cpp_Newbie Maybe you misunderstood the assignment and therefore tries to solve it the wrong way. If you can provide the assignment somehow it might be more clear what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want Set semantics, don't use a Set.  The point of a Set is that it **does not** contain duplicates. It is a simple contradiction to have a Set that contains entries 'a' and 'b' where a.equals(b).

So the question is, what are you actually trying to achieve?  It seems that you want a collection:

1. That can contain 'equal' elements
2. That is ordered.
3. That can look up an entry directly by value.
4. That can do the lookup in at worst O(log N) time

I am guessing at these requirements since you don't actually give any requirements, you simply make an unsatisfiable assertion as to the answer you want.

The best approach I can come up with is a `TreeMap<String,ArrayList<String>>`. Use the value as a key; this gives you a list of all objects with that value.

A second approach might be to have a `TreeMap<String, Integer>` where the integer value is used to count occurrences. This works for Strings, but may not work for other objects where there are important differences between 'a' and 'b' even if 'a.equals(b)' is true.

But that still seems very weird, and I don't understand your use case.

Comment: Im student and my Homework is to create a TreeSet that gives an output with duplicates. Of cause this is not logic, but the task is clear. So if it is unachievable I give up thx for help anyway.

Comment: The requirements seem contradictory, as I said. Maybe you misunderstood, or you're paraphrasing the requirements in a way that makes me and others think they mean something different to the way they're intended?

Comment: The task says I have to add 10 fruits to a TreeSet, 2 of the fruits are double, so the output is 8 fruits in total. But the task says they have to be 10. I do not think I misunderstood the task, also the phrase "Duplicates are wanted in the TreeSet" is very clear. I don't know how to deal with this task, so sry for the stupid question.

Comment: Well, not necessarily stupid - but it does seem like a contradictory requirement given the conventional interpretation of terms.  Can you ask the instructor for clarification?